# How do I rename all object as same as their material name?

Tags: python, scripting, materials, objects

Newbie. I have a scene with so many objects. I want to rename them at a single time same as their material name. How do I do that? Is their any script/plugin?

Answer (score 3):

**Name objects after active material**

May or may not work as you expect.  All objects could share one material and hence renaming would end up with objects named "Material", "Material.001", ... following the blender naming convention for unique object names.

An object can have many materials.

Test script have renamed every object in scene after the name of its active material if it has one.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from bpy import data

# all objects
all_objects = data.objects
# scene objects
scene_objects = context.scene.objects
# selected objects
selected_objects = context.selected_objects

for ob in scene_objects:
    if ob.active_material:
        ob.name = ob.active_material.name
```

for all objects in blend edit and use

```
for ob in all_objects:
    ....
```

similarly for `selected_objects`

Comment: thank you so much, 
It worked perfectly
what if i want to rename with material's diffuse map/base color (or whatever map used for the color texture) name?

for ob in all_objects:
    if ob.active_material:
        ob.name = ob.active_material.name.Diffuse_MAP_NAME

i meant something like this